# get database called recursively error only on HTC Sensation XL

Tags: android, sql, sqliteopenhelper

I'm working on a application where the database is imported like in this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

This works fine on most devices,only at HTC Sensation XL it doesn't work.

Thanks for your Help

Here is error code

11-02 21:35:33.748: W/System.err(14878): java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReadableDatabase called recursively
11-02 21:35:33.748: W/System.err(14878):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:245)
11-02 21:35:33.748: W/System.err(14878):    at at.klettern.database.DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:54)
11-02 21:35:33.748: W/System.err(14878):    at at.klettern.database.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:148)
11-02 21:35:33.758: W/System.err(14878):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:183)
11-02 21:35:33.758: W/System.err(14878):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:249)
11-02 21:35:33.758: W/System.err(14878):    at at.klettern.database.DatabaseRouten.(DatabaseRouten.java:39)
11-02 21:35:33.758: W/System.err(14878):    at at.klettern.wachauclimbing.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:28)
11-02 21:35:33.758: W/System.err(14878):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
11-02 21:35:33.768: W/System.err(14878):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
11-02 21:35:33.768: W/System.err(14878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
11-02 21:35:33.768: W/System.err(14878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
11-02 21:35:33.768: W/System.err(14878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-02 21:35:33.768: W/System.err(14878):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
11-02 21:35:33.778: W/System.err(14878):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 21:35:33.778: W/System.err(14878):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-02 21:35:33.778: W/System.err(14878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
11-02 21:35:33.778: W/System.err(14878):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 21:35:33.778: W/System.err(14878):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 21:35:33.788: W/System.err(14878):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-02 21:35:33.788: W/System.err(14878):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-02 21:35:33.788: W/System.err(14878):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What android version are running on this device? [I found some fatal errors Android 2.1 or less.]

Otherwise, I have been able to cannibalize most if not all of the tutorial you reference and it works flawlessly from 2.2 and up.